# How to Force SSL on Google App Engine Flexible Environment

Tags: php, google-app-engine

Is there documentation showing how to force HTTPS on Google App Engine - Flexible PHP?

I tried placing `secure` on app.yaml and I had no luck.

I also tried in the **nginx-app.conf** placing this but no luck.

I also tried

```
set $test "";

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
    set $test "http";
}

if ($test = 'http-non-cron') {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

Other Option I tried

```
<?php     
     header("Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload");  
     exit();  
?>
```

but no luck.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48755788/4495081

Comment: @DanCornilescu, could you show examples with the X-Forwarded-Proto?

I reviewws the link from https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HTTP_Strict_Transport_Security_Cheat_Sheet but I would like a PHP Example

Comment: I didn't use it myself, I just remembered seeing the answer with the pointer to the official docs.

Comment: Not a PHP user either, but I see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php

Comment: @DanCornilescu can you please convey your message(s) in an answer? The community would benefit from having the answer as an _answer_ and you as well :) Or, if you consider the question as a duplicate, flag it. Thank you and mulțumesc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enforce HTTPS traffic to Google App Engine with custom domain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48752601/how-to-enforce-https-traffic-to-google-app-engine-with-custom-domain)

Comment: @DanCornilescu the answer is not posted in the link as the secure header in app.yaml has been deprecated

Comment: Yes, that's mentioned in one of the answers to that question.

Answer (score 2):

Use the following code (remove `-non-cron` from the comparison):

```
set $test "";

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
    set $test "http";
}

if ($test = 'http') {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

If you have cron handler, you have to allow http access for those handlers with configurations like the following:

```
set $test "";

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
    set $test "http";
}
if ($request_uri != '/cron/') { # everything under /cron/
    set $test "${test}-non-cron";
}
if ($test = 'http-non-cron') {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```