# How to force SSL in NodeJs/Angular App Google App Engine

Tags: node.js, angular, google-app-engine, ssl

I want to launch a web application on Google App Engine.

It is a NodeJs/Angular App with frontend and backend which I deployed as separate services following this guide: https://medium.com/@rgoyard/how-to-deploy-a-single-page-application-and-its-backend-to-google-app-engine-353ff93bd38c using client.yml for deploying the frontend, api.yml for the backend and dispatch.yml for routing all request to /api to the backend service.

I also added a custom subdomain to the app and have the SSL certificates managed by google.

Now the only thing left to do is to force SSL, so when I visit http://subdomain.domain.com I automatically get redirected to https://subdomain.domain.de. On the standard appspot domain created by google everything works fine.

Now I tried so many ways to solve this, that I don't know wether the app is running in a standard or flex environment, so tried everything I found.

The docs say for the standard environment you should use `secure: always` in app.yml like in this question [Google App Engine - Redirect HTTP to HTTPS](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48024061/14021965). It didn't work and this is how I configured it:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
service: default
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: immocheck/index.html
    upload: immocheck/index.html
  - url: /
    static_dir: immocheck
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto
```

Then I tried configuring nginx-app.conf following this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/49370832/14021965 but it didn't work:

```
set $test "";

if ($http_x_forwarded_proto = 'http') {
    set $test "http";
}

if ($test = 'http') {
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

And then I thought maybe I'm on a flexible environment even though I thought I was on standard. So I found something about using the helmet package in the docs and followed this very detailed answer implementing it: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51689825/14021965

Unfortunately that didn't work either and now I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solved my problem:

```
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe: true
service: default

handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: immocheck/index.html
    upload: immocheck/index.html
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
  - url: /
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    static_dir: immocheck
```

Thank you for getting me on the way @GAEfan.

Answer (score 0):

Your first `/` handler matches, and never gets to the `secure: always` directive.  Try:

```
handlers:
  - url: /
    static_files: immocheck/index.html
    upload: immocheck/index.html
    secure: always

  - url: /  # <-- this url will never get hit, as it already matched above, so try this:

  - url: /(.*\.(html|gif|png|jpg|js|css))$
    static_files: immocheck/\1
    upload: immocheck/.*\.(html|gif|png|jpg|js|css)$
    secure: always

  - url: /.*
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto   
    secure: always
```

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. I implemented your suggestion with regular expressions. After that I could reach https just like before but got a 404 trying to navigate straight to http.

Comment: When I left out the part with the regular expression it worked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you wrote a NodeJS/Angular App but from the yaml file I see that the app is in Python 2.7. In order to define the proper runtime, please change your `runtime` element with:

```
runtime: nodejs12
```

[Here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref) you may find all the necessary information about the yaml configuration file and its elements.

You also mentioned:

> I don't know whether the app is running in a standard or flex
> environment.

When you don't define the `env` element, the app is deployed on App Engine Standard. You may confirm this by navigating through the:

> 1. Navigation Menu > App Engine > Version
> 2. Checking under the "Environment" tab  of the current version.

As you mentioned correctly, to force HTTPS for your app, specify the `secure: always` element for **each** handler in your app.yaml. [Reference](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#handlers_secure)

To redirect all the connections of your custom domain to use HTTPS, you will have to set up [SSL certificates](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/securing-custom-domains-with-ssl#verify_a_managed_certificate_has_been_provisioned) and then set the [Strict-Transport-Security header](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-requests-are-handled#forcing_https_connections) in your responses. Please keep in mind that you may chooce between Google Managed or using your own certificates.

I would also suggest you looking the [Node.js Quickstart for App Engine Standard](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/how-to), and taking a look at the [How-to-Guides](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref), in order to get more insight on how to set up your environment and design your application.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know how to find out what environment I'm running on. It's actually Standard. As for the runtime: I followed this Medium Post https://medium.com/@karthiksagar/how-to-deploy-angular-8-app-on-google-cloud-platform-gcp-cdd79e5cc5cf deploying the service and it worked straight away. I never questioned that the runtime should be python27 because I'm only serving compiled files from the dist folder. And it shouldn't be a problem since the app is deployed in a standard env I should be able to configure everything in the app.yaml file, shouldn't I?

Comment: SSL cerfificates (Google managed) are already installed.

Setting the Strict-Transport-Security header in app.yaml like so `Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains` broke everything resulting in 404 on both http and https.